# Display layered navigation links in footer

Tags: layered-navigation, navigation

I want to display the links layered navigation which shows all products that have a certain attribute value.

For example, I have 3 categories with products in them. Each category can have different manufacturers for products. I want the footer to have a link for manufacturer which shows all products with that manufacturer regardless of which category they are in. I want to have multiple sections in the footer where each section will do this for a different custom attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a layered navigation solution but it will do what you're describing.  You'll want to put this code in an extension and pull it in as a block in your footer instead of just placing it in `footer.phtml`.

```
$attribute_code = "gender"; // your attribute code
$attribute_value = 93;    // id of the attribute value
$product_limit = 3;        // number of products to return

$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
              ->addAttributeToSelect('*')  // return all attributes. you can add additional lines to pull specific attributes to be more efficient
              ->addFieldToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>$attribute_code,'eq'=>$attribute_value))) 
              ->setPageSize($product_limit) // number of products to return
              ->setCurPage(1);

foreach ($product_collection as $product) {

    $product_name = $product->getName();
    // you can pull all the attributes you want to display here

    echo '<div class="product">'.$product_name.'</div>';
    // create your product layout and display the data here
}
```

Comment: I only want the link for an attribute in the footer, not the product name. I think it probably requires a bit of logic that needs to be put into an extension. The Amasty Improved Layered navigation extension might accomplish what I want. I just wanted a way to do it without a full extension.

Comment: You can put whichever attribute you want.  `$product->getName()` was just an example.

Comment: @ChrisMcKnight I haven't really dug into this; but I have ripped the 1.9 topnav apart and I would suggest more closely mimicking its behavior (if that is indeed what you're building on) by using varien_data_trees to simplify the development/rendering process - http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Varien/Varien_Data/Varien_Data_Tree.html Also- loading additional product models on every page is likely going to add a noticeable amount of load time to your whole site. You may want to look into using Elasticsearch to do this. LMK if you want a more detailed answer/example and I can whip one up.